# how to take an image file in a string format from amazon s3 using a python code, and use that string in my further code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

how to further proceed with 'obj', how to take the image data into a string from 'obj' to use this image data in my code further ?

Is there any PIL method to use ? or any other way to directly open the image and bring it into a string ?

When i try to download the image

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('temp-bucket')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=bucket, key='img.jpeg')

with open('filename', 'wb') as data:
    obj.download_fileobj(data)



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-0b1921b1e068>", line 2, in <module>
    obj.download_fileobj(data)

  File "/home/django/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 648, in object_download_fileobj
ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)

  File "/home/django/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 566, in download_fileobj
return future.result()

  File "/home/django/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 73, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()

  File "/home/django/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 233, in result
    raise self._exception

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you download a file from S3 with boto

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('temp-bucket')
obj = bucket.Object('img.jpeg')
obj.download_file('/tmp/img.jpeg')
```

If you want to use a file obj download you can use

```
with open('/tmp/img.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
    obj.download_fileobj(f)
```

Documentation for the library is [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a s3 bucket object  to s3.Object bucket_name parameter.   The [doc](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#id195) show it only accept a string.

This will fix the issue.

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name = 'temp-bucket', key='img.jpeg')
```

Also check the documentation for better way to perform task.

The API let you download file directly or load it to your memory variable. I.e. `boto3.resource.s3.download_file()` download file, so it expect a filename as in string. You don't need to open a file object.

`boto3.resource.s3.download_fileobj()` read the object into file object, here, you specify the fileobj, using the with open() statement.

If you read the documentation, you should see the different.

> download_file(**Filename**, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)
>
> download_fileobj(**Fileobj**, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)

So instead of open a file and writing the object, you can download the file directly.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_name = 'temp-bucket'
# bucket name must be string, not a object object.
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=bucket_name, key='img.jpeg')

# reuse the key name specify above to save it to you local folder
obj.download_file(obj.key)
```

p/s: please refer to @Colwin answer how to pass s3 object from Bucket to Object across the chain.

Comment: so if I have a bucket, inside that bucket have a folder inside that folder has another folder and then have my image files, i.e 

bucket/folder/folder/*image_files* 

and I would like to download each file as a temp file in a loop so that i can add that file in a string. 

is that possible ?

Comment: @AbhishekJangid  : object key name in S3 is just arbitrary name. You are free to use python `os.path` split to grab the formatted "path alike" object name to achieve your objective.  Honestly, I don't understand what you mean "add that file in a string"